# How do I test a route slug component in sveltekit?

Tags: sveltekit, vitest

I have this page:

```
src/item/[slug]/+page.svelte
```

trying to render it in vitest gives me an error:

```
  ...
  render(item)
  ..
```

After a trial and error session I narrowed down the cause, it is because the component is a slug, the parameter doesn't get initialized in the tests.

```
import {page} from '$app/stores'

let param = $page.params;
let slug = param.slug
```

how can I initialize it in my test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,for a work around I placed the entire contents of my +page.svelte to a new svelte component file and created an export variable for the slug value

item.svelte

```
<script>
export let itemId;
</script>
<div>
...
```

and in my slug page this is the only code remained:
+page.svelte

```
<script>
import {page} from '$app/stores'

let param = $page.params;
let slug = param.slug
</script>

<item bind:slug={slug}></item>
```

and just ran my tests on the separate component.